# Gradle - Write Task Output Into A File

Tags: java, gradle

I am working with Gradle 7.1, and I am trying to write some of the tasks resuts into a file.
Specifically, I would like to write the output of `dependencies` task into a file after each `jar` task execution.
Looking for some solutions, I understand that at first I need to have `jar.finalizedBy(dependencies)` in order fot it to run.
However, I can't find how to redirect the `dependencies`'s specific output into a file. All the solutions that I have found discuss `Exec` tasks, which `dependencies` isn't.
I am looking for somehing like `dependencies.doFirst(///REDIRECT HERE)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `dependencies` task write to file by attaching a `StandardOutputListener`:

```
tasks.named('dependencies').configure {
    it.logging.addStandardOutputListener(new StandardOutputListener() {
        @Override
        void onOutput(CharSequence charSequence) {
            project.file("$buildDir/dependencies_task_output.txt") << charSequence
        }
    })
}
```

This can also be done with any other Gradle task.